# useEffect with react-hooks/exhaustive-deps where callbacks depend on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a hooks problem I've been unable to find an answer for. The closest article being [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327893/2602327).

Essentially I want to have a function that is invoked once per component lifecycle with hooks. I'd normally use `useEffect` as such:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  doSomethingOnce()  
  setInterval(doSomethingOften, 1000)
}, [])
```

I'm trying not to disable eslint rules and get a `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning.

Changing this code to the following creates an issue of my functions being invoked every time the component is rendered... I don't want this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  doSomethingOnce()
  setInterval(doSomethingOften, 1000)
}, [doSomethingOnce])
```

The suggested solution is to wrap my functions in `useCallback` but what I can't find the answer to is what if `doSomethingOnce` depends on the state.

Below is the minimal code example of what I am trying to achieve:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const getRandomNumber = useCallback(
    () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    []
  );

  const startCounterWithARandomNumber = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(getRandomNumber());
  }, [setCount, getRandomNumber]);

  const incrementCounter = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, [count, setCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    startCounterWithARandomNumber();
    setInterval(incrementCounter, 1000);
  }, [startCounterWithARandomNumber, incrementCounter]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter {count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see from [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-browser-cspr8?file=/src/App.js:23-706) since `incrementCounter` depends on `count` it gets recreated. Which in turn re-invokes my `useEffect` callback that I only wanted to be called the once. The result is that the `startCounterWithARandomNumber` and `incrementCounter` get called many more times than I would expect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I should have pointed out, this is a minimal example of a real-use case where the events are aysncronous.

In my real code the context is a live transcription app. I initially make a fetch call to GET `/api/all.json` to get the entire transcription then poll `GET /api/latest.json` every second merging the very latest speech to text from with the current state. I tried to emulate this in my minimal example with a seed to start followed by a polled method call that has a dependency on the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated your code considerably.

## Solution

If you want the `startCounterWithARandomNumber` function to run once to set initial state, then just use a state initialization function.

```
const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
const [count, setCount] = useState(getRandomNumber);
```

As for the effect setting up the interval, you will also want to only run this once when mounting. Move the interval callback that "ticks" and increments the `count` state ***into*** the effect callback so it is no longer a dependency. Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state and not the initial state. Don't forget to return a cleanup function from the `useEffect` hook to clear any running interval timers.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const incrementCounter = () => setCount((c) => c + 1);
  const timer = setInterval(incrementCounter, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, []);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit useeffect-with-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-where-callbacks-depend-on-state]

Full code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(getRandomNumber);

  useEffect(() => {
    const incrementCounter = () => setCount((c) => c + 1);
    const timer = setInterval(incrementCounter, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter {count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Update

I guess it's still a bit unclear what your real code and use case is doing. It seems you've written your `doSomethingOnce` and `doSomethingOften` functions in such a way so as to still have *some* outer dependency that when used inside an `useEffect` hook is flagged by the linter.

Based on your counting example here an example that doesn't warn about dependencies.

```js
const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

const fetch = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() < 0.1) { // 10% to return new value
        resolve(getRandomNumber());
      }
    }, 3000);
  });

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const doSomethingOnce = () => {
    console.log('doSomethingOnce');
    fetch().then((val) => setCount(val));
  };
  
  const doSomethingOften = () => {
    console.log('doSomethingOften');
    fetch().then((val) => {
      console.log('new value, update state')
      setCount(val);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    doSomethingOnce();
    const timer = setInterval(doSomethingOften, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  // This effect is only to update state independently of any state updates from "polling"
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => setCount((c) => c + 1);
    const timer = setInterval(tick, 100);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter {count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is sort of a contrived and "tuned" solution though since the "fetch" only resolves when it's returning a new value. In reality if you are likely polling and completely replacing a chunk of state that the component ***isn't*** regularly modifying (at least I hope it isn't as this makes merging/synchronizing more difficult). I can improve this answer if there were a better/clearer view of what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help @drew-reese. I was trying to create a minimal example of my real use case which is asynchronous.

In my real code the context is a live transcription app. I initially make a fetch call to `GET /api/all.json` to get the entire transcription then poll `GET /api/latest.json` every second merging the very latest speech to text from with the current state.

I tried to emulate this in my minimal example with a seed to start followed by a polled method call that has has a dependency on the current state.

Comment: @adambutler Ah, I see, I think you missed the mark a bit then. Can you update your question to include a more representative code example?

Comment: I've updated my reply and original post to clarify it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @adambutler The use-case is still a bit unclear but I've updated my answer to include asynchronous calls based on your counting example. My guess is that you've written your `doSomethingOnce` and `doSomethingOften` functions to have an outer dependency and this is flagged by the linter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the usecase you want to solve so keeping minimal code changes to your code.
A very simple solution would be to increment counter as

```
const incrementCounter = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1);
}, [setCount]);
```

This way the increment counter does not rely on count.

Forked from your sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-architecture-t58bs